# Custom ResourceBundle in ADF with only one class

Tags: java, locale, oracle-adf, jdeveloper, resourcebundle

Due to my project's requirements, I have implemented a custom java ResouceBundle class to take resource data from a directory configured in web.xml.
My intention is to have only **one ResourceBundle class** in the project, and whatever resource and language added in the future can be done **without redeploying the whole project**.
For example: MainBundle.java

```
public MainBundle() {
    super();
    this.locale = ADFContext.getCurrent().getLocale();
    readBundle();
}

public MainBundle(Locale locale) {
    super();
    this.locale = locale;
    readBundle();
}

private void readBundle() {
    bundleFileName = baseBundleName + "_" + locale.toString();
    // do some file reading here
}
```

I have implemented the ResourceBundle class to load the correct language according to the current locale. However, if I have only one ResourceBundle class, **when a user login, all other concurrent users' locales are changed into that user's locale**, thus changing their languages. For example: an English user is using my website. A French user logs in, and the English user is suddenly forced to use the website in French.

In order to solve this, I had to create a class for every locale, that extends the MainBundle class, such as MainBundle_en_US, MainBundle_fr, etc. These classes just contain  super() calls in their constructors, nothing more.
However this defeats the purpose of **not having to modify the project** when a new language is added.

My question is:

How can I get around this and just have only ONE resource bundle class?

Is there anyway to achieve what I want, which not having to modify the project when a new language is added?

Answer (score 0):

Don't extend your calss from ResouceBundle Class and implement your own localization/Internationalization framework, then you will have a complete control on your design approach.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! Thanks for your answer, however, it is a bit unfinished. Can you provide examples, maybe some code with explanations? See [how to answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer) for more details.